# Solving for $x$. Trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(56-3x)=-0.441$, where $0\leq x\leq 360$.

I can't seem to do this question, as I knwo its CAST diagrams but I am not sure how to change the values and Find the correct answer. Please Help

Comment: Can't you use the $\cos^{-1}$ function?

Comment: I have now answered this. Thankyou though.

Comment: x=17.991 I hope you got that.

Answer (score 0):

Apply $cos ^{-1}$:
$$56-3x=cos^{-1}-0.441\approx 116.167\Rightarrow 3x\approx -60.167\Rightarrow x\approx-20.05.$$